How we compute $\sup_{\delta \geq 1} e^{-x^2(\delta^2-\delta+1)}$
I need to compute
$$\sup_{\delta \geq 1} e^{-x^2(\delta^2-\delta+1)}$$ where $x\in (0,1)$. Using the fact that $x\in (0,1)$ I see that we can write
$$-\delta^2-x^2<-\delta^2 x^2+\delta x^2-x^2<-\delta -x^2$$ which implies
$$  \sup_{\delta \geq 1} e^{-\delta^2-x^2}< \sup_{\delta \geq 1}  e^{-\delta^2x^2+\delta x^2-x^2}<  \sup_{\delta \geq 1} e^{-\delta -x^2}$$ The functions $f(\delta, x) = e^{-\delta^2-x^2}$ and $g(\delta, x) = e^{-\delta -x^2}$ for $x=0.39$ are visualized with black and purple, respectively, below. The intersection points are on $\delta=0$ and $\delta=1$.

Can you please someone cast some light? I am not familiar with such problems.

Hint: Do you want to maximize or minimize the exponent?

If $x=0$, then it is easy. If $x\neq 0$, then you are looking at a parabola which opens up downwards. Where will you find the minima of this function on an interval?

@SeverinSchraven thanks for the comment. I did an edit in the post. So we can say that
$$e^{-1-x^2}< \sup_{\delta \geq 1}  e^{-\delta^2x^2+\delta x^2-x^2}<  e^{-1 -x^2}$$
which implies that $\sup_{\delta \geq 1}  e^{-\delta^2x^2+\delta x^2-x^2}$ equals to $e^{-1 -x^2}$? Thus $\delta=1$ is the optimal value in the $\sup_{\delta \geq 1}  e^{-\delta^2x^2+\delta x^2-x^2}$?

$f:\delta\mapsto\delta^2-\delta+1$ is increasing on $[1/2,\infty)$ hence $\min_{\delta\ge1}f(\delta)=f(1)=1$, so
$\max_{\delta\ge1}e^{-x^2f(\delta)}=e^{-x^2}$.

Thanks for the answer. We need $\min_{\delta\ge1}f(\delta)$ as $e^{-x^2f(\delta)}$ is a decreasing function with some fixed $x^2$. Thus minimizing $f(\delta)$ we actually maximize $e^{-x^2f(\delta)}$.  Am I rational?

Yes, that is it.
